# get index of for loop when using formset django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

template:

```
 <ul>
    {% for image in obj.images_set.all %}                                   
      <li class="col-lg-4 text-center">
      <a data-toggle="modal" 
      datatarget="#myModal{{forloop.counter0}}"> 
  <img src="{{ image.image.url }}" alt=""/></a>
    </li>

  {% endfor %}

 </ul>
                            <!-- end panel -->
 </div>


 {% for image in obj.images_set.all %}


 <div id="myModal{{forloop.counter0}}" class="modal fade" 
  role="dialog">
 <div class="modal-dialog" style="text-align:center;">
                                <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content" style="display:inline-block;">
         <img src="{{ image.image.url }}" alt=""/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {% endfor %}
```

Im using a for loop on images which has a image set ..Im using modals here so the id should be modal1,modal2 modal3 etc and get incremented on each looping ..But as of now ,it is not incrementing ...How to do this?The imageset for each loop has a maximum of 3 and min of one image!

Comment: is your images getting displayed?

Comment: YEs @Exprator  But when i load the model..Its always taking index of first image in all three images

Comment: that is the problem with how you have defined your modals, you need to put the modal code inside this forloop of image and also mention id in the modal defination as counter

Comment: Please recheck my code @Exprator